# Does HEAD Function work on Client side in Nuxt JS?

Tags: nuxt.js, seo, server-side-rendering

In Nuxt2, I want to display the values ​​from the API with asyncData on the Server side with the Head function in the Page Source. As far as I can see, the HEAD function works on the client side. How can I add Title, Description and Keywords values ​​from API to Source Files?

```
async asyncData() {
  console.log('AsyncData')
}

created() {
   console.log('Created')
}

head() {
  console.log('Head')
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt2 uses [vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) to update the headers and html attributes of your page using the "head" method, you simply have to return the data as an object

Checkout the below example from [Nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/head/)

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'Hello World!'
      }
    },
    head() {
      return {
        title: this.title,
        meta: [
          // hid is used as unique identifier. Do not use `vmid` for it as it will not work
          {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'My custom description'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can also checkout the [Nuxt Meta Tags and SEO for more examples](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/)

Comment: How do I run the Head part on the Server Side? Object is not added to Page Source.